# Extra whitespace between stacked divs on chrome (android) and safari (iphone) only

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue where my website displays correctly on my laptop (chrome/windows), including in the mobile emulator.  But there is an additional horizontal whitespace between the .container-top div and the .projects div that shows up on my pixel (chrome) and on my friend's iphone / safari. It does render correctly on Firefox on my phone.

This is how it displays on my laptop (correct, with no whitespace between down-arrow and first image):

[image: Correct display on laptop]

This is a screenshot from my phone (incorrect - additional whitespace between down-arrow and first image):

[image: Incorrect display on chrome/android]

Any idea why this might be happening?

[Link to my test site.](http://ultramoderne.net/test/projects.html)

HTML and CSS below.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

@font-face {
 font-family: "Tw Cen MT Bold";
 src: url("font/TCB_____.TTF");
}

@font-face{
 font-family: "Tw Cen MT";
 src: url("font/TCM_____.TTF");
}

/* Body */
html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
body {
 font-family: "Tw Cen MT";
 background-color: #ddd;
 color:#000;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 200;
 font-size: 10px;
}
/* Container */
.container {
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 text-align: left;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
.container-top {
 display: block;
 position: static;
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 width:100%;
}
 .navlinks {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 11;
 }

.projects {
 display: block;
 position: static;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
}
 .carousel {
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -0.13em;
  margin-bottom: 0.10em;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 0px;
 }
  .carousel-cell {
   width: 100%;
   height: 850px;
   padding: 0;
   margin:0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  .carousel img {
   display: block;
   margin:0;
   margin-right: auto;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
  }

.video4to3 {
 width: 1145px;
 height: 850px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border: none;
}

.projecttext {
 width: 95%;
 padding-right: 5%;
 font-size: 48px;
 letter-spacing: 0.02em;
 line-height: 1.146em;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #e3e3e3;
}
.about {
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 48px;
 letter-spacing: 0.02em;
 line-height: 1.146em;
 width: 90vw;
}

b {
 font-family: 'Tw Cen MT Bold';
}
.bigtext {
 font-family: 'Tw Cen MT Bold';
 position: relative;
 white-space: nowrap;
 text-overflow: clip;
 font-size: 144px;
 line-height: 0.64em;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0;
 margin-left:-0.07em;
 vertical-align: bottom;
 z-index: 11;
}
/*.bigtext:hover {
 text-decoration:line-through;
 text-decoration-style:dotted;
 text-decoration-color: cyan;
}*/
.bigtext a  {
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:line-through;
 text-decoration-style:dotted;
 text-decoration-color: cyan;
}

/* Smaller phones */
@media (max-width: 320px) {
 
 .bigtext {
  font-size: 31px;
 }
 .projecttext {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 .about {
  font-size: 12px;
 }
 .carousel {
  margin-top: -0.02em;
  margin-bottom: 0.03em;
 }
 .carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 );
 }
 .carousel-cell img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }
 .video4to3 {
  width: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 * 4 / 3 );
  height: 100%;
 }

}
/* big phones / Small Tablets */
@media (min-width: 321px)and (max-width: 767px) {
 
 .bigtext {
  font-size: 42px;
 }
 .projecttext {
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .about {
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .carousel {
  margin-top: -0.03em;
  margin-bottom: 0.05em;
 }
 .carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 );
 }
 .carousel-cell img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }
 .video4to3 {
  width: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 * 4 / 3 );
  height: 100%;
 }

}
/* iPad etc */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1096px) {
 .bigtext {
  font-size: 72px;
 }
 .about  {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
 .projecttext {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
 .carousel {
  margin-top: -0.1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
 }
 .carousel-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 );
 }
 .carousel-cell img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }
 .video4to3 {
  width: calc( 100vw * 2 / 3 * 4 / 3 );
  height: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Ultramoderne&#x2E3A;Architecture&#x2E3A;Providence RI</title>
<link href="css/ultranew.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flickity.css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/flickity.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="js/hash.js"></script>
<script>
 function swapText(elem, text) {
  elem.innerHTML = text;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Main Container -->
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-top">
  <div class="navlinks">
   <div class="bigtext" style="margin-left: -0.045em;">
    <a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
    </div>
   <div class="bigtext">
    <a href="index.html" id="top">PROJECTS</a>
    </div>
   <div class="bigtext">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="bigtext" 
     style="margin-left:-0.01em; margin-top: -0.02em; overflow-y: hidden; 
      background-image: url('images/down-arrow.svg'); background-repeat: no-repeat;"><a href="#top" style="overflow: hidden; margin:0; padding:0;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div class="projects"> 
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "pageDots": false, "draggable": ">1", 
            "wrapAround": true, "prevNextButtons": false, "hash": true , "lazyLoad": 2 }'>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p101">
    <img data-flickity-lazyload="./images/vacant01.gif" />
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p102">
    <div class='projecttext'>An oversize textile hangs within the industrial warehouse: a floating tabula rasa. The lightweight fabric hangs in a subtle catenary shape, creating new spaces and environments without the construction of a single wall. Monumental voids cut into the fabric lightly define rooms within the larger space, while a careful choreography allows the textile to animate between states twice during the night: from a low&mdash;lying plane that clears the space to floating overhead canopy&mdash;and back again.<br /><br />Table's Clear was an installation for the Architectural League of New York's Beaux Arts Ball 2016.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p103">
    <img data-flickity-lazyload="./images/rwp_01.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p104">
    <img data-flickity-lazyload="./images/stl17.jpg" />
   </div>
    </div>
  <div class="bigtext" style="margin-left:-0.02em">
   VACANT PROVIDENCE
   </div>
  <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "pageDots": false, "draggable": ">1", 
            "wrapAround": true, "prevNextButtons": false, "hash": true , "lazyLoad": 2 }'>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p201">
    <img data-flickity-lazyload="./images/triennial01.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p202">
    <div class='projecttext'>An oversize textile hangs within the industrial warehouse: a floating tabula rasa. The lightweight fabric hangs in a subtle catenary shape, creating new spaces and environments without the construction of a single wall. Monumental voids cut into the fabric lightly define rooms within the larger space, while a careful choreography allows the textile to animate between states twice during the night: from a low&mdash;lying plane that clears the space to floating overhead canopy&mdash;and back again.<br /><br />Table's Clear was an installation for the Architectural League of New York's Beaux Arts Ball 2016.</div>
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p203">
    <img data-flickity-lazyload="./images/rwp_01.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-cell" id="p204">
    <iframe class="video4to3" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/152848442?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </div>
 </div>
  <div class="bigtext" >
   RISD TRIENNIAL
   </div> 
  <div class="bigtext">
   <a href="buildings.html" id="top">BUILDINGS</a>
   </div>
  <div class="bigtext">
   <a href="index.html">ULTRAMODERNE</a></div></div></div></body></html>
```

Comment: On iOS, the problem seems to stem from the conflict between `100vh`, `position: static` and the auto-hiding Safari footer. Whether you want to use relative positioning or something else than the view height depends on what you expect the "correct" behavior to be in such a case. If you want to debug the issue further, you can launch the iOS simulator and remote debug it with Safari (at least on macOS, don't know about Windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly from Google developer's website: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing
The problem is that giving height: 100vh to an element that isn't position: fixed will resize the element as if the scroll bar is always shown.
Same thing seems to happen in iOS too: https://medium.com/@susiekim9/how-to-compensate-for-the-ios-viewport-unit-bug-46e78d54af0d

Comment: This seems to answer it.  Thank you!  Now to figure out how to troubleshoot the js on iOS safari...